# jquery slide and hide section divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slide

With this html

```
 <div id="main-content">
        <section id="search-section" class="active">Test 1
             <button id="new-person" data-section="person-section" type="button">
               New Person
             </button>
         </section>
        <section id="person-section">Test adfs </section>
    </div>​
```

I am trying to simply on the `new-person` click slide in the `person-section`.

Two problems i am having:

1. I can't see to have the person-section hidden, i want to on initial load have only my `search-section` visible.
2. With the following javascript, jquery the sliding section is not found with the query selectors i am using. Any thoughts on how to achieve this or is there an existing plugin that already does this.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#new-person').click(function() 
       {  
              event.preventDefault();
               var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-section"),
               $toSlide= $("#"+sectionId),
               $fromSlide= $('.active');

           if (!($toSlide.hasClass("active")))
           {

               $fromSlide.animate({"left":"-100%"},500,'linear')
               $toSlide.animate({"left":"0%"},500,'linear',function()
               {
                   $fromSlide.css("left","100%");
                   $fromSlide.removeClass("active");
                   $toSlide.addClass("active");
               });

           }

       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I hid `person-section` by pushing it left of the view area. Did this by giving it a `left` and `position` style. Don't forget to give it's containing parent `position:relative`. Not sure where you were going with `$fromSlide` so I removed it and cleaned up the code.

```
<div id="main-content" style="position:relative;">
        <section id="search-section" class="active">Test 1
             <button id="new-person" data-section="person-section" type="button">
               New Person
             </button>
         </section>
        <section id="person-section" style="position:absolute; left:-100px;">Test adfs </section>
    </div
```

--

```
$('#new-person').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sectionId = $(this).attr("data-section");
    $toSlide = $("#" + sectionId);

    if (!($toSlide.hasClass("active"))) {
        $toSlide.animate({
            "left": "0%"
        }, 500, 'linear', function() {
            $toSlide.addClass("active");
        });
    }
    else {
        $toSlide.animate({
            "left": "-100%"
        }, 500, 'linear', function() {
            $toSlide.removeClass("active");
        })
    }
});
```

View working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fP7DL/

Comment: The $fromSlide is there so i can replace it with the $toSlide, your solution still shows the active section, i want to replace one with the other. A.V's solution does this but it makes the section's fixed and i want them relative